# pause an infiniteTransition animation in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need to create a button that can play/pause an animation. I was able to switch between two different modifiers. One that is animating and one that is still, but when you go from the pause modifier to the playing modifier it jumps forward because the float was still being animated. Any suggestions for what I need to do, to play/pause an animation?

```
var playing by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val coefficient by transition.animateFloat(initialValue = 0f, targetValue = 1f, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween()))
Column() {
    Button(onClick = {
        //need to play/pause the anitmation
        playing = !playing
    }) {
        if (playing) {
            Text("Pause")
        } else {
            Text("Play")
        }
    }
    Text("I am rotating!", modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
        rotationZ = 360f * coefficient
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you need text rotation at last rotated place or at initial place on pause?

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to be at initial position on pause then you need a small change in your code i.e., an **if** condition in **rotationZ**:

```
var playing by remember {
mutableStateOf(true)
}
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val coefficient by transition.animateFloat(initialValue = 0f, targetValue= 1f, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween()))
Column() {
    Button(onClick = {
        //need to play/pause the anitmation
        playing = !playing
    }) {
        if (playing) {
            Text("Pause")
        } else {
            Text("Play")
        }
    }
    Text("I am rotating!", modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
        rotationZ = if(playing) 360f * coefficient else this.rotationZ
    })
}
```

And if you want to stop text rotation on **last rotated place** then you need to add an extra variable that will hold the last coefficient value on stop:

```
var playing by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

var lastRotation by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0f)
}

val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

val coefficient by transition.animateFloat(initialValue = 0f, targetValue = 1f, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween()))


Column() {
    Button(onClick = {
        //need to play/pause the anitmation
        playing = !playing
        lastRotation = coefficient
    }) {
        if (playing) {
            Text("Pause")
        } else {
            Text("Play")
        }
    }
    Text("I am rotating!", modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
        rotationZ = if (playing) 360f * coefficient else 360f * lastRotation
    })
}
```

Hope this answer helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue on multiple occasions and I have found a solution using easing. Here, we incrementally change the animation if the animation is playing, and we keep it the same if it is paused.

For this example, the behavior is as follows:

- Animation starts at 0%
- Animation is paused at X% completion
- Animation persists at X% completion (as if it froze in place at the time of pause)
- Animation resumes from X% when play is pressed

The `it: Float` from the `Easing` function represents the percentage of time elapsed for the animation. I am using this percentage to calculate roughly how much the animation has progressed each frame. `rateOfChange` and `lastEasingValue` are used to calculate this. `rateOfChange` is then used to increment `desiredEasing` if and only if the animation is not paused. `desiredEasing` is clocked around 1f to represent a complete cycle.`desiredEasing` is used as the calculated easing value.

```
var rateOfChange = 0f
var lastEasingValue = 0f
var desiredEasing = 0f
var playing by remember {
  mutableStateOf(true)
}
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val coefficient by transition.animateFloat(
  initialValue = 0f,
  targetValue = 1f,
  animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
    tween(
      durationMillis = 10000,
      easing = {
        rateOfChange = if (it < lastEasingValue) rateOfChange else lastEasingValue - it
        lastEasingValue = it
        desiredEasing = if (playing) (desiredEasing + rateOfChange) % 1f else desiredEasing
        desiredEasing
      })
    ),
  )
```

Use this coefficient in place of the one you had before

```
Column() {
   Button(onClick = {
     //need to play/pause the anitmation
     playing = !playing
   }) {
     if (playing) {
       Text("Pause")
     } else {
       Text("Play")
     }
  }
  Text("I am rotating!", modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
    rotationZ = 360f * coefficient
  })
}
```

**DURATION WAS SET TO 10000 TO BETTER SEE THE BEHAVIOR**

[Example with easing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx3Eu.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of `rememberInfiniteTransition`:

> Creates a InfiniteTransition that runs infinite child animations. Child animations can be added using InfiniteTransition.animateColor, InfiniteTransition.animateFloat, or InfiniteTransition.animateValue. **Child animations will start running as soon as they enter the composition, and will not stop until they are removed from the composition.**

In fact there is no real feasible way to pause InfiniteTransition's child animations. You can only make them stop, not pause them at some point and then resume them from same point.

Additionally, I'd like to point out that some of the answers contain inaccuracies.

```kotlin
var playing by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val coefficient by transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween())
    )
var lastRotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

Column {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            lastRotation = coefficient
            playing = !playing
        }
    ) { Text(text = if (playing) "Pause" else "Play") }

    Text(
        text = "I am rotating!",
        modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer {
            rotationZ = if (playing) 360f * coefficient else 360f * lastRotation
        }
    )
}
```

The code above uses a tricky way to make the animation appear to be "paused" at a certain moment, but actually infinite child animations still running in the background. InfiniteTransition has been continuously calculating and updating the value of coefficient.

`rotationZ = if (playing) 360f * coefficient else 360f * lastRotation`

This line of code is also being executed repeatedly, but because the value of isPlaying is false after button is clicked, rotationZ is assigned the same value repeatedly, so that it feels like infinite child animations are really paused, but in fact it's not.